# Can't resolve 'fs' using webpack and react

Tags: node.js, webpack, fs, docxtemplater

I keep getting the error in the description when I try to build my application for my Node server.

I am ultimately trying to read a .docx file for docxtemplater, but without 'fs' working, it's not looking to bright.

I have tried to use the node:{fs:"empty"} workaround that I've seen on many solutions, but it's still giving me the same error or propagating up to the console when I am running it on the browser.

Here is what I have in my webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
//var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
var DashboardPlugin = require('webpack-dashboard/plugin');

const sourcePath = path.join(__dirname, './front_end');
const buildPath = path.join(__dirname, './src/bin');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    //home directory for webpack must be absolute
    //context: sourcePath,
    //Application Execution and Webpack Bundling
    entry: {
        js: path.join(sourcePath, 'index.js')
        //html: './index.html',
    },
    output: {
        //Must be absolute path
        path: sourcePath,
        //publicPath: buildPath,
        //publicPath: path.join(__dirname, '/src/bin'),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: [
            '.webpack-loader.js',
            '.web-loader.js',
            '.loader.js',
            '.js',
            '.jsx'
        ],
        modules: [
            path.join(__dirname),
            "node_modules"
        ],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$|\.jsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    "babel-loader",
                    "eslint-loader",
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    "file-loader",
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(gif|png)/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    "url-loader"
                ]
            }
        ],
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$|\.jsx$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2016', 'react']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader',
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: "file?name=[name].[ext]"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                loaders: [
                    'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
                    'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
     ],
    stats: {
        assets: true,
        colors: true,
        errors: true,
        errorDetails: true,
        hash: true,
    }
};
```

Comment: There is no "file system" to load data from, so if you need that data on the web, either rewrite your logic so you can ask for that data by calling your server, use the browser's ability to load assets through `<img>` and `<link>` etc. or use a special loader that lets you bundle them in.

Answer (score 17):

You can't use any modules that come with the Node Core API in the browser, they just won't work there. Node Core Modules rely on C/C++ binaries which won't be present in the browser. So you'll need to find an equivalent approach to replacing any `fs` use in  your react app.

One approach would be to serve the file you want to work with over HTTP via a Node JS backend to your React app. You could read the file using `fs` in your Node server, and place that logic within a route, call that route from your React App via HTTP and stream it back. Then you will have the file data within your React App and can work with it as you need.

[This GitHub repo](https://github.com/webpack/node-libs-browser) has a listing of Node Core Libraries that Webpack has ported over for browser usage. Unfortunately `fs` isn't one of them.

Comment: This was a helpful pattern for me @peteb -- thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

Add in package.json

```
  "browser": {
    "crypto": false,
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false,
    "net": false,
    "stream": false,
    "tls": false
    },
```

Add in webpack:

```
node: { fs: 'empty' },
  devtool: options.devtool,
  target: 'web', // Make web variables accessible to webpack, e.g. window
```

Comment: node: { fs: 'empty' } no longer works in webpack 5

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming late, but this is docxtemplater specific.

To load a docx, you use `fs` in node, and `JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent` in the browser.

See this demo (from here : http://docxtemplater.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generate.html#browser)

```
<html>
    <script src="docxtemplater.js"></script>
    <script src="jszip.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/file-saver.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jszip-utils.js"></script>
    <!--
    Mandatory in IE 6, 7, 8 and 9.
    -->
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="examples/vendor/jszip-utils-ie.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script>
    function loadFile(url,callback){
        JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url,callback);
    }
    loadFile("examples/tag-example.docx",function(error,content){
        if (error) { throw error };
        var zip = new JSZip(content);
        var doc=new Docxtemplater().loadZip(zip)
        doc.setData({
            first_name: 'John',
            last_name: 'Doe',
            phone: '0652455478',
            description: 'New Website'
        });

        try {
            // render the document (replace all occurences of {first_name} by John, {last_name} by Doe, ...)
            doc.render()
        }
        catch (error) {
            var e = {
                message: error.message,
                name: error.name,
                stack: error.stack,
                properties: error.properties,
            }
            console.log(JSON.stringify({error: e}));
            // The error thrown here contains additional information when logged with JSON.stringify (it contains a property object).
            throw error;
        }

        var out=doc.getZip().generate({
            type:"blob",
            mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
        }) //Output the document using Data-URI
        saveAs(out,"output.docx")
    })
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

for me it was happening because I was importing the `tailwind.config.js` into the frontend code to parse some variables from it (using 'tailwindcss/resolveConfig'). Since my config had plugins that were importing the `fs` - I got that error. So I just split the pure config data and plugins code. And my `tailwind.config.js` now imports and merges both (data + plugins), and the JS app imports the data file only (without plugins that use prohibited dependencies)