# Can't resolve error appears only in my webpack-build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, webpack

I'm trying to import a module `_module_name_` into my current react-project with typescript, say `react-app` for reference. The project is bundled up with webpack. I'm importing it into one of my *.tsx* components. The module that I am importing was written by me and I published it on npm. I'm getting a `cannot resolve` error when building my react project. It cannot resolve the `fs` module, apparently. I wonder what causes this problem? Here is the error output:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/_module_name_/index.js 2:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 
'/path/to/project/node_modules/_module_name_'
resolve 'fs' in '/path/to/project/node_modules/_module_name_'
   Parsed request is a module
   using description file: /path/to/project/node_modules/_module_name_/package.json (relative path: .)
      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
      resolve as module
```

The `_module_name_` is extremely simple. For all practical purposes it looks like this:

```js
// index.js
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs');

function foo() {
    const abi = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('file.json', 'utf8'));
    return abi
}

module.exports = {
    foo
};
```

Then I have a typescript declaration file:

```js
// index.d.ts
export function foo(): any;
```

Of course I have the file itself:

```json
// file.json
{
    "a": 1
}
```

and I have a `package.json` in that `_module_name_` which contains at least the following entries:

```json
// package.json
{
    "main": "index.js",
    "types": "./index.d.ts",
    "dependencies": {
        "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**Remark:** When I am in my react project `react-app` I have no problems importing `foo` in any old javascript file or typescript file. It will work perfectly unless it's part of the react app. How strange is that. Maybe it has to do with my webpack loaders, cause I'm using webpack to bundle the app.

**Question:** Is the problem on the side of the `_module_name_` or on the side of the `react-app`?

Comment: what's the name of the module?

Comment: It's called @leomarlo/voting-registry-contracts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just had a quick read, but basically you are trying to use nodeJS in the browser. that's not a good idea. have a look here: [Can't resolve 'fs' using webpack and react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775168/cant-resolve-fs-using-webpack-and-react)
requiring the files and then parsing should work

Comment: Thanks, that explains my problem. Apparently I cannot even use 'fs' because it's using binaries that cannot be understood by the browser.